# CLR Memory Management in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I m using SQL server 2012 SP3 , I want to know if CLR is using Max server memory(bufferpool) or it is using memory out of max server memory because if I check Memoryclerk , seems SQLCLR have separate row as below. I saw one page mentioned from SQL Server 2012, CLR is included in max server memory. Please advice

[image]

Comment: I think that all memory clerks are under the hut of max server memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference: [Memory Management Architecture Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/memory-management-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15)

**Changes to Memory Management starting with SQL Server 2012 (11.x)**

> In earlier versions of SQL Server ( SQL Server 2005 (9.x), SQL Server
> 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2), memory allocation was done using five
> different mechanisms:
>
> **Single-Page Allocator (SPA)**, including only memory allocations that
> were less than, or equal to 8-KB in the SQL Server process. The max
> server memory (MB) and min server memory (MB) configuration options
> determined the limits of physical memory that the SPA consumed. The
> Buffer Pool was simultaneously the mechanism for SPA, and the largest
> consumer of single-page allocations.

> **Multi-Page Allocator (MPA),** for
> memory allocations that request more than 8-KB.

> **CLR Allocator**,
> including the SQL CLR heaps and its global allocations that are
> created during CLR initialization. Memory allocations for thread
> stacks in the SQL Server process.

> **Direct Windows allocations (DWA)**,
> for memory allocation requests made directly to Windows. These include
> Windows heap usage and direct virtual allocations made by modules that
> are loaded into the SQL Server process. Examples of such memory
> allocation requests include allocations from extended stored procedure
> DLLs, objects that are created by using Automation procedures (sp_OA
> calls), and allocations from linked server providers.

> Starting with
> SQL Server 2012 (11.x), Single-Page allocations, Multi-Page
> allocations and CLR allocations are all consolidated into a "Any size"
> Page Allocator, and it's included in memory limits that are controlled
> by max server memory (MB) and min server memory (MB) configuration
> options. This change provided a more accurate sizing ability for all
> memory requirements that go through the SQL Server memory manager.

Max server memory controls the SQL Server memory allocation, compile memory, all caches (including the buffer pool), query execution memory grants, lock manager memory, and CLR memory (**essentially any memory clerk found in sys.dm_os_memory_clerks**).

That does not mean all memory required for CLR execution is controlled by `max server memory` settings.DLL by a third party (not published by Microsoft) will still use memory that is NOT accounted for within `max server memory` setting.

> Memory for thread stacks, CLR, extended procedure .dll files, the
> OLE DB providers referenced by distributed queries, automation objects
> referenced in Transact-SQL statements, and **any memory allocated by a
> non SQL Server DLL are not controlled by max server memory**.

I suggest reading [this blog post](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/how-much-memory-does-my-sql-server-actually-need/) by Jonathan Kehayias especially the comments.

[Effects of min and max server memory on SQL CLR](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4e308ff-db40-4a68-a1a2-49da4c6ed6f6/effects-of-min-and-max-server-memory-on-sql-clr?forum=sqldatabaseengine) Q&A confirms the above assertion.

Comment: I don't understand on this part  "1 CLR memory is managed under max_server_memory allocations starting with SQL Server 2012 (11.x)." according to Microsoft page but the same page also mentioning "Memory for thread stacks1, CLR2, extended procedure .dll files, the OLE DB providers referenced by distributed queries, automation objects referenced in Transact-SQL statements, and any memory allocated by a non SQL Server DLL are not controlled by max server memory." What is that CLR2 which is not control by max server memory?

Comment: this is the Microsoft page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/memory-management-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Sorry about those 1 and 2; they were markers for the footnote. I added an explanation about third-party dll.